# C line order reversed by compiler?

Tags: c, stdio

I've got this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int addOne();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char s[100];
    int x = 1;
    x = addOne(x);
    printf("%d",x);
    gets(s);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int addOne(int j) {
    return j + 1;
}
```

You can see that printf is before gets(s), but when I run the code it asks the string first, after it prints the number. I'm using NetBeans with Cygwin gcc compiler. Is there something I miss? Is it a compiler error?

Comment: You missed the part about how it is undefined behavior if you run it and enter a string with over 99 characters.

Comment: this line: `int addOne();`  is not correct,  it should be: `int addOne( int );`

Comment: the function: `gets()` was depreciated and in the latest standard, completely removed.  Suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanly compile.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) For instance,  the compiler will raise warnings about 1) unused parameter `argc`  2) unused parameter `argv[]`  3) not to use depreciated function `gets()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`printf()` is usually line-buffered. So printf's output doesn't appear on the screen until the buffer is flushed.

Add `\n` to the printf and it should work as expected.

```
printf("%d\n",x);
```

You can disable the buffering if it's not needed using `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`.

By the way, you should never `gets()`. Use `fgets()` instead. Because `gets()` is prone buffer overrun vulnerability and has been obsoleted since C99 and has been removed completely from C11.

---

Regarding your suspicion that compiler is re-ordering the lines: It's true that compiler *can* re-order instructions and is allowed to do so legally.
But only as long as it doesn't affect *observable effect* of the program.

Consider the following code,

```
void func(void)
{
   int a = 2;
   int b = 3;

   a = a * 2;  //line 1
   b = b + 3;  //line 2

   printf("%d\n", a+b);
}
```

Compiler can compute either `a` or `b` in any order (line1 or line2) as it wouldn't affect the behaviour of the code. Or it can even simply replace the function with:

```
void func(void)
{
   printf("%d\n", 10);
}
```

Typically, compiler would do such transformations for optimization purpose and is allowed. In your code, compiler can't do such code transformations as it would affect the observable behaviour of your code.

Comment: Thanks. Using the `\n` itself not working, only with the `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`. Calling `fflush(stdout)` after `printf` is working too.

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` is definitely a good fix.  You can use it also when you want to ensure a debug message a written to the console synchronously when trying to locate an elusive bug.